# SQL query to find all students having two or more particular subject

Tags: mysql

I need to find all the students from class who has Eng and Maths books.

Table structure is simple

```
Student    
==========================
id |  First Name  | Last Name

1  |  Akhil       | Kumar
2  |  Nikhil      | Tylagi
3  |  Pawan       | Benarjee


Student Books    
==========================
id |  student_id  | book

1  |  1      | Eng
2  |  2      | Maths
3  |  3      | Physics
4  |  1      | Maths
5  |  2      | Physics
6  |  3      | Eng
```

What I am able to create is:

```
SELECT student_id
from student_books OStu
WHERE book = "Eng" AND (SELECT book FROM student_books
                        WHERE book = "Maths" AND student_id = OStu.student_id);
```

From above Akhil is only one who should be retrieved

```
Expected Result should be    
=====================================
student_id |  First Name  | Last Name
=====================================
1          |  Akhil       | Kumar
```

Now the problem is what if Some one wants to query for students having (Eng, Maths, Physics upto let say 30 books).

Is there any nicer way to do it. (<-- By this i mean, Do I have to reconsider my design approach? As, I may need same thing for upto 30 books)

Comment: Show us the expected result!

Comment: `student_books` or `Student Books`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HAVING` clause to filter only those who have both `Maths` and `ENG` :

```
SELECT t.student_id
FROM student_books t
WHERE t.Book IN('Maths','Eng')
GROUP BY t.student_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.book) = 2
```

If you also want their names:

```
SELECT s.first_name,s.last_name,t.student_id
FROM student_books t
INNER JOIN Student s 
 ON(t.student_id = s.id)
WHERE t.Book IN('Maths','Eng')
GROUP BY t.student_id, s.first_name,s.last_name
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.book) = 2
```

If you want aditional books, just play with the `WHERE` and `HAVING` , for 3 change them to this:

```
WHERE t.Book IN('Maths','Eng','Physics')
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.book) = 3
```

Comment: Second query is invalid. (Do a self join instead!)

Comment: @jarlh What am I missing ? :S

Comment: GROUP BY issue. At least more recent MySQL versions wont run that query. (Perhaps older versions will, returning an unpredictable result.)  

    The general GROUP BY rule is:
    If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Yea, but this is true for Oracle, SQL-Server ... Not MySQL. MySQL may mess up the results, but it will only happen when there is more then one option. That's not the case.. @jarlh

Comment: Newer MySQL versions are stricter. (Unless some compatibility mode is set.)

Comment: Really? I don't really program in MySQL, I assumed it's the same :) I'll add an aggregation function then.

Comment: Two ways to resolve this MySQL issue: either specify all columns to `GROUP BY`, or wrap your query with an outer one, that collects all the data using the filtered ids.

Comment: DISTINCT *should* be redundant, as a UNIQUE key *should* be formed on  (student_id,book) - in fact, this is a valid PRIMARY KEY, rendering the id obsolete.

Comment: Assuming that the data is valid, and that those columns are unique.. I always prefer to use `DISTINCT` since I never know the OP DDL's unless he post them, and by the content of this tables I assume they're small, so it won't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Note that we are doing a self join on three copies of the student_books table:

```
SELECT sb1.id,
FROM student_books sb1
INNER JOIN student_books sb2 ON (sb1.studentid = sb2.studentid) AND (sb1.book <> sb2.book)
INNER JOIN student_books sb3 ON (sb1.studentid = sb3.studentid) AND (sb1.book <> sb3.book) AND (sb2.studentid <> sb3.studentid)
WHERE sb1.book  = "Maths" AND sb2.book  = "English" AND sb3.book  = "Physics"
```

Comment: Well , I didn't downvote it, and this answer will work. Note that you are doing 2 unnecessary joins, and you are multiplying your results by a lot with out checking `sb1.book` <> `sb2.book` ...

Comment: Didn't downvote either. This does the job, but is really inefficient. Imagine what happens if you want 8 books.

Comment: plus one for @GaborSch, Query should be efficient, it just an example in reality i have to programmatically generate quesry for n number of books.

Comment: It's tedious to write, but it's not really inefficient.

Comment: I understand, and I have added additional predicates for better optimization. My query in my belief would work well for fewer books(like 3), though it won't scale for a greater number of books (like 8). No good database would do a whole cross product join on 3 copies of the same table and then consider the predicates one by one.

Answer (score -2):

You should use INNER JOIN OR EQUAL. Query time is fastest with the same result.

```
//option1
SELECT Student.Id AS student_id,
Student.FirstName,
Student.LastName
FROM Student, StudentBooks  
WHERE Student.Id = StudentBooks.Id AND
StudentBooks.book IN ('Eng', 'Maths')
GROUP BY Student.Id

//option2
SELECT Student.Id AS student_id,
Student.FirstName,
Student.LastName
FROM Student INNER JOIN StudentBooks ON (Student.Id = StudentBooks.Id)
WHERE
StudentBooks.book IN ('Eng', 'Maths')
GROUP BY Student.Id
```

Comment: This returns also those students who have Eng book, but does not have Maths book,

Answer (score -2):

Try this if you need students with **eng, maths and physics books**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Student
        JOIN
    student_books ON Student.id = student_books.student_id
WHERE
    student_books.book = 'Maths' AND student_books.book = 'Eng' AND student_books.book = 'Physics';
```

Else if you need students with **eng, maths books**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Student
        JOIN
    student_books ON Student.id = student_books.student_id
WHERE
    student_books.book = 'Maths' AND student_books.book = 'Eng';
```

Comment: How can a column contain two or three values at the same time?